# Фраза «только ради бога постарайтесь…» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частицы

Полное предложение:
*Хорошо, только ради бога постарайтесь не вызывать нареканий со стороны шефа и его кузена.*
Возможно, не хватает запятой после «ради бога»?
Может быть, предложение должно выглядеть так: «Хорошо, только ради бога, постарайтесь не вызывать нареканий со стороны шефа и его кузена»?

Answer (score 3):

Можно не выделять ***ради бога***, но если выделять, то ставить запятые следует с двух сторон.

*— Хорошо, только, ради бога, постарайтесь не вызывать нареканий со стороны шефа и его кузена.*

[**РАДИ БОГА** / **ХРИСТА** / **ВСЕГО СВЯТОГО**, частица](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_647)

> В художественной литературе встречаются примеры необособления этих частиц.

Answer (score 3):

В орфографическом словаре:
[**ради бога**](https://lopatin.academic2.ru/119906/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0), *в значении частицы* (пожалуйста, очень прошу; делай как хочешь, я нисколько не возражаю).

В словаре Ожегова:
**ради бога** (*разг.*) — пожалуйста, || очень прошу, ради всего святого. Замолчи ты ради бога! Помогите ради бога!

Нашелся и [контекст](http://rulibs.com/ru_zar/sf/vale/2/j5.html) (думаю, его стоит привести).

> — Я порекомендовал бы вам обратиться в министерство, например, к государственному секретарю по вопросам печати.
>   — Понял.
>   — Вы читаете их журналы?
>   — Нет. Но я начну.
>   — Хорошо, только ради бога постарайтесь не вызывать нареканий со стороны шефа и его кузена.

Если предположить, что выделительно-ограничительная частица [только](http://endic.ru/academic/Tolko-65017.html) (в значении "единственно, исключительно") относится к "ради бога", то получается употребляемая конструкция **только ради бога** — *частица + частица* (в значении "только очень прошу").
В этом случае запятыми может выделяться вся конструкция.
*— Хорошо, только ради бога, постарайтесь не вызывать нареканий...*

*Только ради бога, княжна матушка, прикажите их прогнать и не ходите к ним* (Л. Толстой).
*Только ради Бога, постарайтесь их ничем не отпугнуть* (Г. Демарев).